# Construct retraction of $conv(X)$ onto $X=[0,1]\times\{0\}\cup\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{1/n\}\times[-1/n,1/n]$

Tags: general-topology, retraction

Let $X=[0,1]\times\{0\}\cup\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{1/n\}\times[-1/n,1/n]$ be subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$. And let $Conv(X)$ be a convex hull of $X$. Construct retraction of this convex hull onto $X$.

If retraction must be continuous, is it even true that such retraction exists? I cannot see it.

Comment: Of course there's no problem with a discontinuous retraction; usually "retraction" entails "continuous". I tend to doubt that such a retraction exists.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, but if we allow discontinuous retractions, then isn't it true that every subspace of $X$ is retract of $X$?

Comment: Yes of course -  that's why I said there's no problem with a discontinuous retraction. And that's why questions "Is there a retraction of $X$ onto $Y$?" are taken to be referring to continuous retractions

Answer (score 0):

If you have a box canyon {0,1}×[0,1] $\cup$ [0,1]×{0},
then a continuous retract from the unit square of the
canyon onto the canyon walls can be effected by an ever
deeping U starting from the top [0,1]×{1}.

Adjust this to each of the box canyons of X and simutanously
apply for all those retractions to obtain the beseached retraction.